# Events disappearing when adding additional dates

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

For one of my sites, a number of events from May and June that were set up as recurring events and had people registered on the event have gone. It's not individual events, it's usually 3 or 4 or more of a set of recurring events that all disappear.

I've just had this from one of the staff
"The dates and information was showing on Tuesday. When I went to create an additional date (using repeat) it wiped all the dates I had previously input."

Is it not possible to go back to a recurring event and add further dates?

Comment: The user has confirmed that this occurred when adding an additional event to one of the repeating events rather than the original. Shouldn't this at least trigger an error message rather than delete events unknowingly?