# Changing the repeat count/end-date on an event

Tags: civievent, repeating-events

I have a repeating weekly event that was set up with 30 repeats, the last one is next week. I need to extend the repetition - it's going to be weekly for the foreseeable.

On the Configure event » Repeat screen, I can't choose a value >30, but I can set an end date far in the future.

However, doing that and pressing Save gives a confirm screen saying:

> ⚠️ There are participants registered for repeating events being removed from the set. Those with participants will be converted to standalone events, and those without registration will be deleted.
>
> A repeating set will be created with the following dates.
>
> ➊ (table listing existing, past events!)
>
> ➋ (table listing events with future start dates)

I'm a bit confused by the ⚠️ warning because there shouldn't be any removed from the set, yet it states that there are; yet I can't see which events those would be?

The first table, ➊ is confusing coming under the "will be created" intro text; these are already created. The second ➋ looks right - these are the dates for future events that I would expect to be listed.

Is it just the wording that's wrong? Perhaps that warning that seems to state it's removing events is not logic-based and doesn't matter? Or is there a way to see the events being removed? Perhaps that's what ➊ is supposed to be?

Clarifications gratefully received!

EDIT: it gets quirkier! The above was observed by editing the last event in the series of repeating events. If I configure the *first* event of the repeating series, put a future date in, then it's weirder still: it seems to list a lot of past-dates in table ➋ and a sub-set of events in table ➊??? Also, one of the events listed to be removed is the original event itself. And it also lists certain dates in both the to-remove and the to-add tables.

EDIT 2:

The first table is listing the events that are to be *removed*.

It's mis-positioned under the title about adding events because of a missing `</table>` tag. (I've done a [merge request to fix that](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26547))

Answer (score 1):

Having spent an hour looking through the code and doing a couple of tests, here's what I think the answer is, but v. grateful to others who can say with more conviction.

1. The confusing title-table mismatch is a simple HTML bug. I've done a [merge request to fix that](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26547). The first table is indeed a list of events that will be:

   - removed from the repeating series, but left alone - if they have participants.
   - deleted if they have no participants. I suspect this answers [Events disappearing when adding additional dates](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19781/events-disappearing-when-adding-additional-dates)
2. At least on Civi 5.58.1 there's a bug that causes submitting this form to crash. I've [reported this](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4368) but can't fix it as I don't know what that code was ever trying to do. On my single test (may not work for you!) commenting [Line 408](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/blob/1edfed415fe687e7c7847df41497352b5fa96368/CRM/Core/Form/RecurringEntity.php#L408) seems to get it to work...